nginx route to different ports
I have a setup were i have a node/express api that i host in a linux container on port 3000.
Then i want to have a websocket service running in the same linux container on port 3001.
I have a simple socket-io that i start like this:
   io = new Server(3001, {
            path: "/socket-io/",
            cors: {
                origin: ["http://localhost:4200", "http://10.0.2.2", "http://localhost", "capacitor://localhost"],
                methods: ["GET", "POST"],
            },
        });

    // Ensure it binds to an IPv4 address
    io.listen(3001, '0.0.0.0'); // Explicitly bind to IPv4

    io.adapter(createAdapter(redisClient, subClient));

    io.httpServer.on('listening', async () => {
        const address = io.httpServer.address();
        const isIPv6 = address.family === 'IPv6';
        const host = isIPv6 ? `[${address.address}]` : address.address;
    
        const bindType = isIPv6 ? 'IPv6' : 'IPv4';
        await logger.logMessage(undefined, undefined, `Socket.IO server is listening on ${bindType} host: ${host}, port: ${address.port}`);
    });        

And this all works fine when I run it locally so I know it works.
Then I have a docker-compose.yml file that creates all my services that looks like this:
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:management"
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=test
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=test
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - test-network
    restart: always

  seq:
    image: datalust/seq:latest
    container_name: seq
    ports:
      - "5341:80"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=seq.test.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=seq.test.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=test@gmail.com
    volumes:
      - ./seq-data:/data
    networks:
      - test-network
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=redis.test.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=redis.test.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=test@gmail.com
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - test-network

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:1.2.2
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./socket-io.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/socket-io.conf
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
    networks:
      - test-network
    restart: always

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - test-network
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    environment:
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=nginx-proxy
      - DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@gmail.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_RENEWAL_DAYS=30
    restart: always

  test-api:
    image: ewr.vultrcr.com/test/testapi:latest
    container_name: test-api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.test.se
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3000
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=api.test.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=test@gmail.com
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - test-network
    restart: always
volumes:
  acme:
  certs:

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge

And then as you can see in the nginx-proxy i add another nginx conf file (socket-io.conf)
upstream websocket_backend {
    server api.test.se:3001;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    location /socket-io/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://websocket_backend;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }

So I want all request that goes to my api.test.se/socket-io/ to go to port 3001 which is my websocket service.
This is the log message I get in my socket listening event:
Socket.IO server is listening on IPv6 host: [::], port: 3001
What am i doing wrong here?

Not a programming question; try [unix.se] or [su], maybe even [sf].

Feel free to report the others/similar ones for closure. I'm not here vetting every single question that gets posted.
